# IBDesignable class don't seems to work properly

Tags: ios, swift, ibdesignable

I'm building a new iOS app with swift and trying to make a custom IBDesignable UIButton class to use in the designer.
My code does not seems to work either in the builder or the app itself at runtime.
The default value i gave to the IBInspectable vars does not apply to them.

```
@IBDesignable class MyButton: UIButton {

@IBInspectable var backColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
    didSet {
        self.backgroundColor = backColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var textColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
    didSet {
        self.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
    layer.cornerRadius = (frame.height / 2)
    setTitle(title(for: .normal)?.uppercased(), for: .normal)
}
}
```

I expect to see the button in the designer/app with a red background and a white text and none of these happens.
I'm using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

add this two func s

```
  override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.setup()
    }
```

no need for init

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a property default value does not invoke the `didSet` clause.
You need something like:

```
    private func setup() {
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
        layer.cornerRadius = (frame.height / 2)
        setTitle(title(for: .normal)?.uppercased(), for: .normal)
        // I would do it differently, but this is just for demo purposes
        // Also, can't assign a prop to itself, so using a temp
        var tmp = self.backColor
        self.backColor = tmp
        tmp = self.textColor
        self.textColor = tmp
    }
```

Additionally, Xcode is not very good with IBDesignable, in swift or objective C.

Make sure the menu item: **Editor -> Automatically Refresh Views** is checked.
You can also explicitly do **Editor -> Refresh All Views**.
From my experience - this stops working after a while, and you need to quit Xcode and restart it to make it work again.

Comment: It did nothing.. do you have any good and full example i could use?

Comment: @EitanaAviv As I said, Xcode is not very good with IBDesignable. Try to make sure the specified menu item is checked, and quit Xcode and restart. I tried it with a sample project and it worked (after restarting Xcode).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your button is set to type `.custom` in your Interface Builder.
   This is not obvious but the default button type is `.system`, which cannot be customized. I saw people having no problems with this but in my applications this was always a problem.
2. Another problem is that if you keep your inspectable values empty, the `didSet` won't be called and the default value won't be applied.

   ```
   @IBInspectable var backColor: UIColor? = UIColor.red {
      didSet {
         updateBackground()
     }
   }

   private func updateBackground() {
      self.backgroundColor = backColor
   }

   func setup() {
      ...
      updateBackground()
   }
   ```